# Add numbers to string

Tags: asp-classic

I have a string that looks like this:

`&s=Chicago,IL&s=Memphis,TN&s=Akron,OH&s=Plainfield,IN&s=Dallas,TX&s=Miami,FL&s=Orlando,FL&s=Valdosta,GA&s=Milwaukee,WI`

sometimes it will be bigger and sometimes it will be smaller.

I would like to assign numbers to every `&s=` so the above example would look like this:

```
&s1=Chicago,IL&s2=Memphis,TN&s3=Akron,OH&s4=Plainfield,IN&s5=Dallas,TX&s6=Miami,FL&s7=Orlando,FL&s8=Valdosta,GA&s9=Milwaukee,WI
```

But I don't know how to do that, any help ?....
THANKS :-)

I tried something like this but it's not working???

```
dim AllLocations
AllLocations="&s=Chicago,IL&s=Memphis,TN&s=Akron,OH&s=Plainfield,IN&s=Dallas,TX&s=Miami,FL&s=Orlando,FL&s=Valdosta,GA&s=Milwaukee,WI"
    dim i
    For i=1 to TotalLocations
    AllLocations=Replace(AllLocations,"&s=","&s" & i & "=")
    Next

    Response.Write(AllLocations)
```

Comment: That's nice. Good luck with that. Did you have a question?

Comment: @MarcB Hello, I would like to assign numbers to every S=.... I don't know how to do that, Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THIS IS IT!

```
    dim AllLocations
    AllLocations="&s=Chicago,IL&s=Memphis,TN&s=Akron,OH&s=Plainfield,IN&s=Dallas,TX&s=Miami,FL&s=Orlando,FL&s=Valdosta,GA&s=Milwaukee,WI"

' You need to add TotalLocations and have it count how many &s's you have so that the For i 1 to knows where to stop.

        dim i,ArrayOfValues,v,ovo

        ArrayOfValues=Split(AllLocations,"&")
        For i = 1 To TotalLocations
            ovo=Replace(ArrayOfValues(i),"s=","&s" & i & "=")
            Response.write ovo
        Next
```

Comment: Like I said a `For` loop. ;-) I'm guessing they are ripping this from a querystring, so what happens if one of the `s(n)` parameters happens to be the first, do you not need to check `?` and remove accordingly?

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like this:

```
string s = "&s=Chicago,IL&s=Memphis,TN&s=Akron,OH&s=Plainfield,IN&s=Dallas,TX&s=Miami,FL&s=Orlando,FL&s=Valdosta,GA&s=Milwaukee,WI";
int i = 1;
var list = s.Split(',');            
var result = list.Select(x => x.Replace("&s", "&s" + i++));
s = String.Join(",", result);
```

Comment: This is [tag:asp-classic] not [tag:c#] or [tag:Asp.net].

Comment: Sorry for that. I didn't make attention. The solution still the same: split your string, replace &s by &sx and join them again. This what I get in mind. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the answer:

```
    var res = "&s=Chicago,IL&s=Memphis,TN&s=Akron,OH&s=Plainfield,IN&s=Dallas,TX&s=Miami,FL&s=Orlando,FL&s=Valdosta,GA&s=Milwaukee,WI";emphis,TN&s=Akron,OH&s=Plainfield,IN&s=Dallas,TX&s=Miami,FL&s=Orlando,FL&s=Valdosta,GA&s=Milwaukee,WI";
  var res = str.split("=");
  for (var i=0; i < res.length; i++) {
    res[i]=res[i]+i;                        
   }
```

I have also write a pen for you, here is the [Link](http://codepen.io/techhysahil/pen/mydYOV?editors=100)

Comment: It works on your page but when I try it says: Expected identifier 
for (var i=0; i < res.length; i++) {   ....also I would like for it to start at number s1 not s0.... THANKS SO MUCH FOR YOUR INPUT AND HELP I HOPE I WILL GET IT WORKING SOON.

Comment: Your example will not work Sahil because it is not ASP (Server Side), Also your example starts with a S0 he wanted S1 and there is a number 9 at the end of the string that should not be there.

Comment: I made the changes in my Pen to get s1 instead of s0 and to eliminate 9 entry at the end.Check out the same link.